# Authenticate user with a URL token in an MVC web application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to add a user authentication flow to an exiting MVC 4 web application, where the user will click on a link in an email that includes a URL token. This should take him to the application and automatically log him in. 
This token could be added to any existing request to allow transparent login.

What would be the right place in the framework to add the check for the token?

Please. **I am aware of the security risks** of this feature. So please don't analyze the security aspects of this.

I **would** like to hear about the possible implementations of this feature

Comment: Will it always be the same MVC action that this link will point to, or are you going to allow this URL token to authenticate *any* request?

Comment: Nowhere?  That's the most insecure thing there is.. unless this is a one-time use token, which is still possible to intercept..

Comment: The right place could very well be very far from any part of your application altogether. Links are easy to copy/paste, and your users could share them without even realizing what is going to happen. Note that this is an expectation formed in part by what well-known apps do -- if I give you a link to my Gmail inbox it won't work for you.

Comment: I haven't implemented this before, but I would assume that you would have a public facing action which would take the token as a parameter, and then compare that to a database entry for the user which also contained the token. If it was valid, then redirect.

Comment: @Mystere Man this would be a one time, or a limited time token

Comment: If you want to add a 'check' I  think a custom implementation of an AuthorizeAttribute? So if the token is not valid, you can abort the action execution etc.

Comment: @RonHarlev I know you specifically stated you aren't interested in the security aspects - however, I *am* interested in why they are irrelevant? If you know this approach is flawed why continue with it? Is security of the users data not important for your particular site?

Comment: @James users sharing URLs is an unlikely scenario. Also the tokens will have a short lifetime

Comment: @RonHarlev I would be concerned more about a malicious user getting their hands on a valid URL, not whether or not users would share their URLs. How short is the lifetime of the token? If you want it to be relatively secure it would need to be pretty short, which in essence makes the feature pointless. This *feels* like a mobile API type authentication you are trying to implement, if it is I would strongly recommend you reconsider as this is **completely insecure**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the cleanest way of doing this would be to implement a custom `ActionFilterAttribute` and add it to the global list of filters.

Something like:

```
[Attribute]
public class TokenLoginAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public overrides void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // Perform your authorization / login based on token here
    }
}
```

In `App_Start\FilterConfig.cs`:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new TokenLoginAttribute());
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: ActionFilter will not work, since the AuthenticationFilters run before the ActionFilter, if they're not authenticated they will get rejected.  Unless you mean to implement this on an action that does not require authentication.

Comment: That all depends on the order of attributes in his filter config. But you're right, a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` would probably be a better solution.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  AuthorizationFilters always execute before ActionFilters, regardless of the order.